# How to properly import time series data from excel into R for analysis

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I'm new to R and have run into a roadblock with some code. I'm importing time series data from excel that looks like this (abbreviated version below) full data range is A1:O124 with A1="DATE":

```
    DATE    MLCIA3CD    ENHG185P    CIBZS1PR    MLCIUKVB
1   2008-01-31  0.001632    -0.000721   0.001985    -0.014482
2   2008-02-29  -0.001620   0.001907    -0.000052   0.003801
3   2008-03-31  0.000657    -0.002661   0.001405    0.021155
4   2008-04-30  0.002729    0.000291    -0.000451   -0.009227
5   2008-05-30  0.000896    0.002460    0.007613    0.002411
6   2008-06-30  0.001253    -0.000667   0.005017    0.022411
7   2008-07-31  0.000790    0.000060    0.001744    0.007149
```

Here's my code -- I'm opening more library's than necessary for this part of the code but I'm using them in other sections of the code that are working.

```
#Commodity Strategies
rm(list=ls())
setwd(file.path("G:","R Scripts"))
library("readxl")
library("Matrix")
library("PortfolioAnalytics")
library("zoo")
library("xts")
library("tseries")
library("nloptr")

xx<-file.path("G:","Commodity Strategies Alphas.xlsx")
mreturns<-read_excel(xx,3,range="A1:O124")
mreturns<-data.frame(mreturns)
row.names(mreturns)<-levels(mreturns$date)[mreturns$date]

##Minimum Variance
init.portf.minvar<-portfolio.spec(assets=mreturns)
init.portf.minvar<-add.constraint(portfolio=init.portf.minvar,type="full_investment")
init.portf.minvar<-add.constraint(portfolio=init.portf.minvar,type="long_only")
init.portf.minvar<-add.constraint(portfolio=init.portf.minvar,type="risk",name="StdDev")
init.portf.minvar
**minvar.lo.ROI<-optimize.portfolio(R=mreturns, portfolio=init.portf.minvar,optimize_method="ROI",trace=TRUE)**

#Results
results<-data.frame(as.vector(minvar.lo.ROI$weights))
colnames(results)<-'MinVar'
```

The three error message I receive is:

```
> minvar.lo.ROI<-optimize.portfolio(R=mreturns, portfolio=init.portf.minvar,optimize_method="ROI",trace=TRUE)
Error in checkData(R) : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.
```

Comment: you must use rownames when dealing with time series; you may do rownames(your_dataset) <- your_dataset$date_column  (must be parsed as date); then you have to delete that date column your_dataset$date_colum <- NULL

Comment: Thank you Elio Diaz. Can you show me in code format what that should look like using "mreturns" as my dataset?